# Trying to match zero outside the word bounderies

Tags: regex

I have patterns like
FQC19515_TCELL001_20190319_165944.pdf
FQC19515_TBNK001_20190319_165944.pdf
I can match word TCELL and TBNK with this RegEX
^(\D+)-(\d+)-(\d+)*([A-Z1-9]+)*?.*

But if I have patterns like
FLW194640_**T20NK**022_20190323_131348.pdf
FLW194228_**C1920**_SOME_DEBRIS_REMOVED.pdf
the above regex returns
T2 and C192 instead of T20NK and C1920 respectively

Is there a general regex that matches Nzeros out side of these word boundaries?

Comment: Regex provided in the post doesnt provide any matches. the question at the end has nothing to do with the details given above? what exactly is the requirement? Please provide examples of input string and matches.

Comment: What is the rule here? I can come up with `^([A-Z]+)(\d+)_([A-Z0-9]+?)\d+_`, see https://regex101.com/r/blgC8N/1, but it does not get `C1920`, why should it be extracted?

Comment: Sorry this regex ^(\D\D\D)(\d\d)(\d+)_([A-Z1-9]+)_?.*.  The important section is in ([A-Z1-9]+) part.  From the string provided above, I need to match for string TCELL, TBNK, T20NK, and C1920 with one general regex rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider all 4 examples of your input:

```
FQC19515_TCELL001_20190319_165944.pdf
FQC19515_TBNK001_20190319_165944.pdf
FLW194640_T20NK022_20190323_131348.pdf
FLW194228_C1920_SOME_DEBRIS_REMOVED.pdf
```

The first group, between start of line and the first "_" (e.g. `FQC19515` in row 1)
consists of:

- a non-empty sequence of letters,
- a non-empty sequence of digits.

So the regex matching it, including the start of line anchor and a capturing group is:

```
^([A-Z]+\d+)
```

You used `\D` instead of `[A-Z]` but I think that `[A-Z]` is
more specific, as it matches **only letters** an not e.g. "_".

The next source char is `_`, so the regex can also include `_`.

A now the more diificult part: The second group to be captured has
actually 2 variants:

- a sequence of letters and a sequence of digits (after that there is
  a "_"),
- a sequence of letters, a sequence of digits and another sequence of
  letters (after that there are digits that you want to omit).

So the most intuitive way is to define 2 alternatives, each with
a respective **positive lookahead**:

- alternative 1: `[A-Z]+\d+(?=_)`,
- alternative 2: `[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]+(?=\d)`.

But there is a bit shorter way. Notice that both alternatives start
from `[A-Z]+\d+`.
So we can put this fragment at the first place and **only the rest**
include as a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`), with 2 alternatives.
All the above should be surrounded with a **capturing group**:

```
([A-Z]+\d+(?:(?=_)|[A-Z]+(?=\d)))
```

So the whole regex can be:

```
^([A-Z]+\d+)_([A-Z]+\d+(?:(?=_)|[A-Z]+(?=\d)))
```

with `m` option ("^" matches also the start of each line).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/GDdt10/1

Your regex: `^(\D+)-(\d+)` is wrong as after a sequence of non-digits
(`\D+`) you specified a **minus** which doesn't occur in your source.
Also the second minus does not correspond to your input.

## Edit

To match **all** your strings, I modified slightly the previous regex.
The changes are limited to the matching group No 2 (after `_`):

- Alternative No 1: `[A-Z]{2,}+(?=\d)` - two or more letters, after them
  there is a digit, to be omitted. It will match `TCELL` and `TBNK`.
- Alternative No 2: `[A-Z]+\d+(?:(?=_)|[A-Z]+(?=\d))` - the previous
  content of this group. It will match two remaining cases.

So the whole regex is:

```
^([A-Z]+\d+)_([A-Z]{2,}+(?=\d)|[A-Z]+\d+(?:(?=_)|[A-Z]+(?=\d)))
```

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/GDdt10/2

Comment: You are awesome.

Comment: What about these patterns FQC19515_TCELL001_20190319_165944.pdf
FQC19515_TBNK001_20190319_165944.pdf?  Your solution returns TCELL001, and TBNK001.  They should return TCELL and TBNK.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you could use:

```
^[A-Z]+\d+_\K[A-Z0-9]{5}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    [A-Z]+          # 1 or more capitals
    \d+_            # 1 or more digit and 1 underscore
    \K              # forget all we have seen until this position
    [A-Z0-9]{5}     # 5 capitals or digits
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NtR8lT/1)